# how to handle votes in ember.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ember.js

I am stuck studying ember.js I have this jsfiddle with the code http://jsfiddle.net/GgGGD/18/ if you check it out you will see that I can vote up and down once I have clicked a particular post name but when I am in the index route I can't make the votes sum up or down, what am I doing wrong? the console says nothing handles the action.

this is the app.js

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('posts');
    this.resource('post', {
        path: ':post_id'
    });
});
App.AplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({



});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        return posts;
    }
});


App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        return posts;
    }
});


App.PostController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    //initial value
actions: {
        voteUp: function () {
            this.set('votes', this.get('votes') + 1);
        },
        voteDown: function () {
            console.log("voting down");
            this.set('votes', this.get('votes') - 1);
        }
    }

});

var posts = [{
    id: '1',
    title: "Rails is Omakase",
    img: "img/img1.jpg",
    author: {
        name: "d2h"
    },
    date: new Date('12-27-2012'),
    votes: 50,
    excerpt: "There are lots of à la carte software environments in this world. Places where in order to eat, you must first carefully look over the menu of options to order exactly what you want.",
    body: "I want this for my ORM, I want that for my template language, and let's finish it off with this routing library. Of course, you're going to have to know what you want, and you'll rarely have your horizon expanded if you always order the same thing, but there it is. It's a very popular way of consuming software.\n\nRails is not that. Rails is omakase."
}, {
    id: '2',
    title: "The Parley Letter",
    img: "img/img2.jpg",
    author: {
        name: "d2h"
    },
    date: new Date('12-24-2012'),
    votes: 546,
    excerpt: "My [appearance on the Ruby Rogues podcast](http://rubyrogues.com/056-rr-david-heinemeier-hansson/) recently came up for discussion again on the private Parley mailing list.",
    body: "A long list of topics were raised and I took a time to ramble at large about all of them at once. Apologies for not taking the time to be more succinct, but at least each topic has a header so you can skip stuff you don't care about.\n\n### Maintainability\n\nIt's simply not true to say that I don't care about maintainability. I still work on the oldest Rails app in the world."
}

];
```

this is the html

```
<body>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars">
   <header>
            <figure id="header_logo">
                <a href=""><img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
            </figure>
            <div id="header_titulo">
                <h2>Puls3 - Dolor Sit amet</h2>
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                       <li> {{#linkTo 'index'}}Home{{/linkTo}} </li>
                        <a href="https://github.com/herrkin/puls3-ember"><li>GitHub</li></a>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <figure id="header_user" >
               <a href=""><img src="img/user.jpg"></a> 
            </figure>
        </header>   

    <section id="contenido">
      {{outlet}}
    </section>
  </script>


  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
   <!-- item -->
    {{#each model}}

            <article class="contenido_item">

                  {{#link-to 'post' this}}<h2>{{title}}</h2>
                    <p class="item_posted">Posted by  {{author.name}}</p>{{/link-to}}



                    <p class ="extra_tag">tagname</p>

                        <a class="likes_up" href="#" {{action "voteUp" this}}> up</a>
                        <div class="likes_numero">{{votes}}</div>
                        <a class="likes_down" href="#" {{action "voteDown" this }}></span> down</a>


            </article>

    {{/each}}

  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="post">
   <!-- item -->
       <article class="contenido_item">

                  {{#link-to 'post' this}}<h2>{{title}}</h2>
                    <p class="item_posted">Posted by  {{author.name}}</p>{{/link-to}}



                    <p class ="extra_tag">tagname</p>

                        <a class="likes_up" href="#" {{action "voteUp" this}}> up</a>
                        <div class="likes_numero">{{votes}}</div>
                        <a class="likes_down" href="#" {{action "voteDown" this }}></span> down</a>


            </article>

  </script>

  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/1.0.0/handlebars.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ember.js/1.0.0/ember.min.js
"></script>


</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/chopper/GgGGD/20/).

You were actually not rendering the `posts` template, but were rendering the 'index' template with its associated (generated) controller. Thus your 'PostController' was never used and all the 'voteUp' and 'voteDown' actions went to the generated application index controller. The following fixed it:

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    {{#each model}}
        {{render 'post' this}}
    {{/each}}
  </script>
```

UPDATE: [This jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chopper/GgGGD/22/) was what answered the question.

Comment: how would I make the indivitual post styled diferently in the post route than it does in the index route?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - you can simply adjust the formatting in the post template. Or do you want to have two ways of rendering a post?

Comment: in my templates I have a class for the articles rendered in index template and a different one in the post template but if I do what you tell me I would be losing the class in the index template, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Ah I see what you are saying. Yes, but you could call the template in the {{render}} helper anything (doesn't have to be `post`). But I think [this](http://jsfiddle.net/chopper/GgGGD/22/) is what you are after. It's a modified version of your original jsFiddle.

Comment: great, you have helped me, I am learning I am giving babysteps with the framework I will keep trying and doing :D