# Ember.js Save Up and Down Vote to the Data

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I used this jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/chopper/GgGGD/22/) from this StackOverflow question ([how to handle votes in ember.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924256/how-to-handle-votes-in-ember-js)) to add Up and Down voting to my Ember site. Like in this fiddle, all my data lives inside my app.js, I have no backed database.

The up and down voting works, but it does not save that data, so it resets on a page refresh. Any help with how to save the change when someone upvotes would be greatly appreciated!

Controller

```
App.ThemeController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
actions: {
    voteUp: function () {
        console.log("voting up");   
        this.set('votes', this.get('votes') + 1);

    },
    voteDown: function () {
        console.log("voting down");
        this.set('votes', this.get('votes') - 1);
    }
}
});
```

Data

```
App.THEMES = [
{
id: 1,
title: 'Decode',
price: '$0',
free: true,
description: 'A minimal, modern theme, designed to be mobile first and very responsive, Decode is built just for Ghost and uses Ghost\'s innovative features to present a beautiful and clean blog.',
columns: 1,
popular: true,
purchaseLink:'https://github.com/ScottSmith95/Decode-for-Ghost',
demoLink:'http://decode-ghost-demo.scotthsmith.com',
image: 'images/decode.jpg',
votes: 0
}, ....
```

Thanks,
David B

Comment: You could use Ember's incrementProperty and decrementProperty to streamline your code. More info here: http://emberjs.com/guides/cookbook/working_with_objects/incrementing_or_decrementing_a_property/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form [Ember.js guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/persisting-records/).

You need to call save() on those objects, something like this.

```
voteDown: function () {
        console.log("voting down");
        this.set('votes', this.get('votes') - 1);
        this.save();
    }
```

**EDIT:** However, if used just that JSFiddle you mentioned, it does not have any data persistence related code. Thus the method will not work. Look up ember-data.

Comment: Thanks, I tried using ember data, (changing App.whatever to App.whatever.FIXTURES) but was running into a ton of problems where data would no longer show up when I would refresh the page. Was hoping there might be another way. Thanks for the response! Maybe I will try again.

Comment: Fixtures are just sample data, to aid development. You need to configure ember-data to use real data store.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have no persistence layer, you app necessarily loses all state when you refresh the page. Generally, people use ember-data for persistence (more info here: http://emberjs.com/guides/models/). If you don't want a backend database, you'll need to use local storage. Check out https://github.com/rpflorence/ember-localstorage-adapter as an addon to ember-data to do this easily. This will allow you to persist changes across refreshes, though it obviously will not sync across machines.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer, I was thinking I could just edit the code in the files itself. Thanks for clearing it up.